# MySQL Two Left Joins Distinguish Same Column

Tags: php, mysql, database

In the following query, I am selecting the one column from users and am expecting a join to take place on both follow_reconciliations user_id and followed_user_id column.

```
SELECT u.ig_user_id FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN follow_reconciliations f ON (f.followed_user_id = u.user_id) 
LEFT JOIN follow_reconciliations f2 ON (f2.user_id = u.user_id)
```

But, I need to know which query the ig_user_id comes from. How can I rename ig_user_id as an alias for each join? What is the best approach to this?

**EDIT:** Visually, this is how I want the results to return

```
+------------+---------------------+
| ig_user_id | followed_ig_user_id |
+------------+---------------------+
| 15325      | 5295                |
+------------+---------------------+
```

This query might be more in the direction of this. It returns the correct results as two rows but they are not renamed as two aliases.

```
SELECT u.ig_user_id AS ig_user_id FROM users u LEFT JOIN follow_reconciliations f ON (f.user_id = u.user_id) 
UNION
SELECT u2.ig_user_id AS followed_ig_user_id FROM users u2 LEFT JOIN follow_reconciliations f2 ON (f2.followed_user_id = u2.user_id)
```

**Second Edit:** This does the trick.

```
SELECT u.ig_user_id AS ig_user_id, u2.ig_user_id AS followed_user_id
FROM follow_reconciliations f
LEFT JOIN users u ON (u.user_id = f.user_id)
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON (f.followed_user_id = u2.user_id)
```

Comment: Your question title asks for inner join whereas your query has LEFT join. Also which table has ig_user_id is unclear from the information provided. Could you mention the table structure?

Comment: Riz, sorry about that. Made an edit on the title and query that should clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives me the results I am looking for:

```
SELECT u.ig_user_id AS ig_user_id, u2.ig_user_id AS followed_user_id
FROM follow_reconciliations f
LEFT JOIN users u ON (u.user_id = f.user_id)
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON (f.followed_user_id = u2.user_id)
```

If anyone has any performance suggestions, please chime in.

Comment: Does the table `users` have both ig_user_id column AND a user_id column?

Comment: If not, then this answer seems quite overkill: You are selecting columns from joins which are explicitly available in the base table (they participate in the join condition)... therefore, zero joins are necessary (unless your example is a great simplification of what you are actually selecting)

Comment: @ctrahey it does. user_id is our identifier for the user and ig_user_id is Instagram's identifier for the user. Follow reconciliations holds the information to what user followed what user with our identifiers but in this case, we need each users Instagrams identifier. From a performance perspective, is there a better way of doing this and still outputting the results with each alias?

Comment: @ctrahey I do select other columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (do I?) you only need one join:

```
SELECT 
  ig_user_id,
  f.followed_user_id as followed_ig_user_id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN follow_reconciliations f USING (user_id)
```

Comment: I may not be explaining this correctly. There should only be one result from each LEFT JOIN since a users user_id is unique so I want to the results to return as if I renamed each ig_user_id to the respective join. I have made an edit to reflect this visually.

Comment: I think I answered my question in an answer I added. Thank you for your time and any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question.. i'm sory if wrong..

`SELECT u.ig_user_id,xx.followed_user_id FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM follow_reconciliations f) as xx ON (xx.followed_user_id = u.user_id) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM follow_reconciliations f2) as yy ON (yy.user_id = u.user_id)`

this query provide you to rename or aliasing every column on table.. :)

CMIIW